# Error encoding zipfile

Tags: python, encoding, python-zipfile

I have several files that I'd like compress with zipfile but occurs one error when the name of the files have graphic accents.

My list of files:

- Adriano Araújo.zip
- André Cerqueira.zip
- Paulo Henrique Guiné.zip

When I compress this files in the filez.zip:

- Adriano Ara·jo.zip
- AndrÚ Cerqueira.zip
- Paulo GuinÚ.zip

The code:

```
from zipfile_infolist import print_info
import zipfile
import os
import fileinput
import glob
files1 = glob.glob( '*.zip' )
for name in files1:
   zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\Users\sergioH\files.zip', mode='a')
   try:
      zf.write('%(name)s' % {'name':name})
   finally:
      zf.close()
      print
```

how to solve this?

Comment: What's your problem? any error messages? You didn't specify what you wanted your code to do and why it doesn't do what you want it to do :)

Comment: the problem is that when I compress the files gives an error coding and file names change.

Comment: files1 = glob.glob( '*.zip' )

Comment: There is not enough information here really, I made several assumptions in my answer that might be incorrect. Is this Python 2 or 3? What is `files1` here? How do you unzip your zip file afterwards?

Answer (score 7):

From the [`zipfile` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write):

> **Note**: There is no official file name encoding for ZIP files. If you have unicode file names, you must convert them to byte strings in your desired encoding before passing them to `write()`. WinZip interprets all file names as encoded in CP437, also known as DOS Latin.

You appear to be using filenames not encoded to CP437 here; you probably want to use a Unicode file path for the `glob()` command, so Python returns Unicode filenames, then encode to CP437 when zipping:

```
from string import maketrans

def encode_cp437(s, _noqmarks=maketrans('?', '_')):
    return s.encode('cp437', errors='replace').translate(_noqmarks)

files1 = glob.glob(u'*.zip')  # unicode path
with zipfile.ZipFile('C:\Users\sergioH\files.zip', mode='a') as zf:
    for name in files1:
        zf.write(name, encode_cp437(name))
```

Note that I used the `ZipFile` object as a context manager to ensure it is closed automatically, and open it just once instead for each filename in the list.

I also used `errors='replace'` to force the encoding to succeed even if there are codepoints not encodable to CP437. Any such codepoints are replaced by Python with `?` question marks, which are also not allowed on some filesystems so we replace those with `_` underscores. **Warning**: this can lead to duplicate filenames!

Comment: Encoding the name does not seem to work. For example when trying to use this on a file named `Čtimne.txt`, I get an `[Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: u'?timne.txt'`.

Comment: @martineau: ah, interesting. Starting a filename with `?` is not allowed, so an additional step of replacing the question marks with some other replacement character might be needed.

Comment: @martineau: I've added translation of `?` to `_` to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but just changing the result of using `errors='replace'` after encoding doesn't help. I think the problem is `zf.write()` can't find the file when given its encoded name — i.e. now the error is `[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '_timne.txt'`.

Comment: @martineau: ick, of course; the translated name is meant to be a separate argument. First argument is the actual filename, second is the archive name.

Comment: @martineau: I'm leaving in the `?` to `_` mapping as that's generally a good idea anyway.

Comment: When I try to create the equivalent archive with WinZip, it just skips the file (without any error message) — may just be an inherent limitation of the zip file format. Using 7-Zip to create a .zip changes the character to `_`. Using 7-Zip to create a .7z archive works even better, it adds the file with the proper filename.

Comment: @martineau: yes, it is a limit of the ZIP format and it is archiver dependent on what codec they'll use for the filename.